# Tool recommendation for screen-sharing with access to remote desktop for a whole team

Tags: jira, remote-access, scrum, screensharing, scrumboard

as COVID put us in a new situation, where everybody is at home we are still struggling with how to do our SCRUM dailies well.
One of the biggest challenges is, that wo do not have a chance to use our JIRA-board as we would do offline. What we usually do now, is that use a video-conferencing-tool (such as Slack, Zoom, Teams) and then somebody starts to share his screen.
But this means, that only this person has control over the screen and can perform any actions on the JIRA board, but now the whole team. Does anybody has a good recommendation, what tool to use where many people have control over one remote computer?

I looked at some tools myself already, but I only found pair-programming-tools (such as tuple.app), but they are focussing on a good collaboration as a pair only. Use-together (use-together.com) go exactly in the right direction as multiple people have a mouse and keyboard at the same time, but unfortunately the limit for people collaborating together is set to 4. As our team varies between 6-8 people this is again no option for us.

As I can imagine that a lot of people might already solved this kind of challenge, I´m happy to hear, how you did it!

Comment: nobody in the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you want your whole team to control the sharing? In my experience it is usually one person driving the Jira and there should be almost nothing to do other than moving between the participants lanes and maybe update someting that was missed before the daily?

If you explain what you do, I am sure we can find a solution for it :)

Comment: Well - we don't do "walk-the-board", where somebody is going through the board from top to bottom. Instead we throw a ball to each participant, who then tells about topics. But this makes it harder for a facilitator, as you would have to say "can you go up again to story 123" or anything like this. So it would be nicer if the person could do it himself - as he would also do in real life.